# Deducing distributions using sample paths properties instead of the opposite

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

It is common in the theory of stochastic processes to "build" stochastic processes by imposing properties on the distribution of the process (see Brownian motion for obvious example: independent normal increments...) and then deduce properties of the sample paths of the process (for the case of Brownian motion, nowhere differentiability $a.s$).

What if we want to do it the other way ? We impose strong sample paths properties, and then ask what are the distributional properties of such a process ?

Here is an example.

Suppose we would like to learn about the distribution of a stochastic process $X_t$ on $(0,1)$ such that the sample paths of the process are $a.s$ continuous, non-decreasing, $X(0^+) = -\infty$, $X(1^-)=\infty$, $\int_0^1 X_t^2 \,dt < \infty$.

What are the distributional properties of such a process ? What are the tools at our disposal to study such a problem ?

Comment: The first question to ask is whether such a process $X_t$ exists.

Comment: Take the quantile function of a normal rv with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$, where $\sigma^2$ is itself a random variable. This gives you a stochastic process on $[0,1]$ with the same characteristics as in my question.

Comment: It seems to me that you have described a family of functions, not a stochastic proccess. In particular it could be almost surely equal to one of these functions, or it could be that which you described.

Comment: Yeah so the question is "can we identify the set of possible distributions given a set of sample paths properties ?"

Comment: If you consider the simpler scenario where $t\in S$ takes finitely many values, ignore the stuff about $\pm \infty$ and you replace $dt$ with counting measure say then the set of distributions is still very unrestricted.I'm not sure how much more restrictive your scenario is, but you can cook up an embedding of these functions into your space of stochastic processes so any theory should be able to say something at least about these functions too, which I feel is unlikely